# Why are my 2 shapes not joining together?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to join two very simple shapes together, as you can see in the picture below.

When I join them, they are still sort of separate. I want to put the bean like shape in the plane so I can extrude, inset etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you happen to have 2 outlines in a plane, like this, you can:

- (Object Mode )<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> join to a single mesh, if not already
- Right-Click menu > Convert to > Curve
- Set the Curve to 2D in its Data Tab > Shape panel, and its fill to anything but 'None' (left, below)

[image]

- Convert back to Mesh, and <kbd>X</kbd> > Limited Dissolve
- For decent topology maybe ..<kbd>F</kbd> fill the hole and <kbd>I</kbd> inset the outside, excluding 'Boundary'
- For tidiness, maybe.. <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>A</kbd> cut orthogonal edges, and <kbd>F</kbd> face-dissolve together the faces divided by the old diagonals.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the *Knife Project* tool: Make 2 different objects, select the plane only, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> select the bean shape, then *Mesh > Knife Project*, it will cut the bean shape on the plane:

[image]

Comment: I get an error saying: No other selected objects have wire or boundary edges to use for projection. Did you join the two different objects?

Comment: no they are separated, select the plane only, switch to Edit mode, Ctrl select the bean, Ctrl left click on the bean, etc